# What is Meliodas' true power level at his highest peak?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

I've been wondering what Meliodas's true peak is. I've seen videos where it says he is 990,000 and 1,000,000, but I'm not sure if I believe that, and does he get more powerful if he's a demon king.

What is Meliodas' true power level at his highest peak?

Answer (score 4):

**Meliodas' ultimate power level has not been officially released by the author.**

The last time Meliodas' power level was estimated, it reached a total of 142 000 (*Volume 29*). This was **Assault Mode Meliodas**, which is theoretically his original form and strength (as described by Merlin and other characters).

However, after his possession by the Demon King, Meliodas indeed increased his power by an unknown amount. Most notably, Meliodas' power is considered so huge that he was decided to to leave Britannia, in order to avoid destroying the country through his sheer presence, which warped the climate / weather by itself. Assault Mode Meliodas did not have such a natural effects on his surroundings.

Answer (score 1):

Meliodas never showed his true personal magic ability, making him stronger than Escanor at high noon. In the story, he says if he were to show his true magic, he wouldn’t be able to live there anymore.